# Eclipse RSE - Setting up Sftp through multiple hops

Tags: ssh, eclipse

So I have my local windows server, we'll call locWin1. I also have two remote linux servers, remLin1 and remLin2.

locWin1 can SSH to remLin1, but not to remLin2. remLin1 can SSH to remLin2.

I am trying to set up an Eclipse RSE SSH only connection where the file browser could edit and save files on remLin2 from locWin1.

So far I have had zero luck in attempting to do so. Is this possible?

Comment: Which client are you using to SSH into `remLin1`?

Comment: I can SSH into it through Putty or MobaXterm, or even the shell that comes with Eclipse RSE. The client doesn't really matter. What I want is to edit the files within Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188555/can-eclipse-rse-connect-to-a-local-port-ssh-tunneled).The answer is that you initially set your connection to `loclahost`. (First you need to create an ssh tunnel `7000:remLin2:22 user@remLin1`). Then you go back in and edit it for the port and user name. The current dialog boxes and steps are just a tiny bit different in that post. Currently, V4.5.1, the steps look like this:

**Connection Dialog** make sure "verify host name" is not checked
[image]

**Right click on connection** if you have the properties window in your view, just click on the connection, you don't need to to bring up the properties dialog.
[image]

**Properties Dialog** set hostname and username (use back arrow)
[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In PuTTY, you can setup a SSH tunnel through `remLin1` so you can access `remLin2`.  When  you setup your connection look under Connection->SSH->Tunnels.  For the "Source port" use any free port on your machine (ie 2222).  For the "Destination" use `remLin2:22`.  Make sure "Local" is selected and push "Add."

Once connected, you will be able to SFTP to `localhost:<port_specified_above>` to access your files.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that easy. Remote connections are done through the Remote System Explorer (RSE) plugin. The dialog box for creating a connection has a slot for hostname, but you can't specify a port. I've been struggling with this and have not yet found a solution. Currently, I'm looking into using PTP Remote Services (as of Mars) http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ptp.doc.user%2Fhtml%2FremoteTools.html  I'll update when I get it working.

Comment: Found solution in other SO post. Posted answer below.